# Binary search does not work with doubles

Tags: java, search, binary

This program works very well with integers, but not doubles. There are no errors, but the program returns -1. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am new to programming.

```
public class binarySearchProject
{
  public static int binarySearch(double[] arr, double x, int high, int low)
  {
    int mid=(high+low)/2;
    if(high==low || low==mid || high==mid)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    if(arr[mid]>x)
    {
      return binarySearch(arr, x, high, mid);
    }
    else if(arr[mid]<x)
    {
      return binarySearch(arr, x, mid, low);
    }
    else if(arr[mid]==x)
    {
      return mid;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    double i = 45.3;
    double[] a = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};
    int size = a.length;
    System.out.println(binarySearch(a, i, size, 0));
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `int`s as well. I tried it.

Comment: Don't know if that's the problem, but shouldn't the array be sorted for binary search to work?

Comment: I think you swapped your cases, too: if mid > x then you should search in the lower half, not in the higher half.

Comment: Is is for exercise purpose ? If no, don't reinvent the wheel and use `Arrays.binarySearch(double[] a, double key)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the conditions:

`if (arr[mid] > x)` should be `if (arr[mid] < x)`

`else if (arr[mid] < x)` should be `else if (arr[mid] > x)`

Also note that in order to make this work, the array must be sorted (That's the whole point of *binary search*), you can use [`Arrays#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28double%5B%5D%29):

```
Arrays.sort(a);
```

I recommend you rename your class so it begins with an upper case (Following Java Naming Conventions).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't catch either problem. The latter is much bigger.

Comment: yep first sort and then call your binary search. And maybe have a few more test arrays to test your function. General software advice after hearing "But sir it works on my desktop with my data !"

Answer (score 2):

As @tobias_k pointed out:

For binary search to work, you need to sort the array first.
See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for details.